# Use enumValues from graphql introspection in SelectInput of react-admin

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin

I'm trying to avoid having this kind of code on my react-admin application:

```
<SelectInput source="currency" choices={[
  { id: 'EUR', name: 'EUR' },
  { id: 'USD', name: 'USD' },
]} />
```

Instead I would like to query the graphql endpoint for the list of available enums and use them in this element.
For this particular example if I do a graphql query like this:

```
query GetEnum {
__type(name: "Currency") {
  enumValues {
    name
  }
}}
```

I get this response:

```
{ "data": {
"__type": {
  "enumValues": [
    {
      "name": "EUR"
    },
    {
      "name": "USD"
    }
  ]
} 
}}
```

I would like to be able to avoid editing my react-admin app when adding/editing the enum options on the API side.

Any ideas if this is already foreseen in react-admin? I can't find any example or use in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to me is to build a new Resource with your currencies.

```js
<Admin {...props}>
    {/* Notice you don't have to set any view to declare a resource */}
    <Resource name="currencies" />
</Admin>
```

That way, you'll be able to use a `<ReferenceInput>` to select your currency in another resource.

```js
<ReferenceInput label="Currency" source="currency" reference="currencies">
    <SelectInput optionText="name" />
</ReferenceInput>
```